# Spam false positive when using MAIL on Linux

Tags: email

I am unable to send the email through Linux. I've installed the mail package and follow the SOP of configuration. Below is my result, issue is
**ACTION: FAILED**. I change my email address to **abc@xyz.com** below. I also tried to use my Gmail address and was unable to send the mail as well.

```
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello. Testing Mail.
Thankyou

--v8C5U2fA002539.1505194202/localhost.localdomain--

From MAILER-DAEMON@localhost.localdomain  Tue Sep 12 10:31:26 2017
Return-Path: <MAILER-DAEMON@localhost.localdomain>
Received: from localhost (localhost)
        by localhost.localdomain (8.14.7/8.14.7) id v8C5VQ9I002567;
        Tue, 12 Sep 2017 10:31:26 +0500
Date: Tue, 12 Sep 2017 10:31:26 +0500
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON@localhost.localdomain>
Message-Id: <201709120531.v8C5VQ9I002567@localhost.localdomain>
To: <root@localhost.localdomain>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
        boundary="v8C5VQ9I002567.1505194286/localhost.localdomain"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)

This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--v8C5VQ9I002567.1505194286/localhost.localdomain

The original message was received at Tue, 12 Sep 2017 10:31:20 +0500
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<abc@xyz.com>
    (reason: 550-5.7.1 This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to aspmx.l.google.com.:
>>> DATA
<<< 550-5.7.1 This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass
<<< 550-5.7.1 authentication checks. To best protect our users from spam, the
<<< 550-5.7.1 message has been blocked. Please visit
<<< 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more
<<< 550 5.7.1 information. q4si8210294wrb.33 - gsmtp
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable

--v8C5VQ9I002567.1505194286/localhost.localdomain
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; localhost.localdomain
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Tue, 12 Sep 2017 10:31:20 +0500

Final-Recipient: RFC822; abc@xyz.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: DNS; aspmx.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550-5.7.1 This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 12 Sep 2017 10:31:26 +0500

--v8C5VQ9I002567.1505194286/localhost.localdomain
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <root@localhost.localdomain>
Received: from localhost.localdomain (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by localhost.localdomain (8.14.7/8.14.7) with ESMTP id v8C5VK9I002565
        for <abc@xyz.com>; Tue, 12 Sep 2017 10:31:20 +0500
Received: (from root@localhost)
        by localhost.localdomain (8.14.7/8.14.7/Submit) id v8C5VJEY002564
        for abc@xyz.com; Tue, 12 Sep 2017 10:31:19 +0500
From: root <root@localhost.localdomain>
Message-Id: <201709120531.v8C5VJEY002564@localhost.localdomain>
Date: Tue, 12 Sep 2017 10:31:19 +0500
To: abc@xyz.com
Subject: Testing Mail
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Testing Mail
Thankyou


--v8C5VQ9I002567.1505194286/localhost.localdomain--
```

Comment: Have you followed all the recommendations from https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication ?

Comment: I have read this recommendations but sorry to say I am unable to understand. Could you please help me out..!!

Comment: I suspect you failed to properly configure DNS to prove your host is indeed responsible for sending emails o  behalf of your domain.